# Possibility to use spatial filters for layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, filter

I like the power of QGIS regarding setting attribute based filtes.

But is it also possible to filter contents of layers based on their location and spatial relations to other layers within qgis projects?

Here is an example: I **only** want features of one shapefile within one qgis project to be displayed (on map canvas **and** within the attribute table) when they touch, intersect or are disjoint from features of another shapefile within the same QGIS project.

I am not talking abaut spatial selects or exports but about instant and dynamic solutions.

I know this is supposed to be possible via using the pluging reffunctions, but it is extremely laggy and produces inconsistent results. I would love to use spatial filters outside symbology panel (rule based) as **global** filters

Comment: This is what PostGIS and Spatialite/SQLite are for... the database does the work, QGIS shows the result.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you're looking for, like providing an example?

Comment: Have you looked into virtual layers?

Comment: I tried to get it work, but maybe I got the syntax wrong. Do you know of any resource that could help me concerning this topic?